# java.lang.ClassCastException-((BigDecimal)myObj[1]).longValue()

Tags: java, classcastexception

I am getting following error while trying to execute following code snippets. Please let me know what are the possible reasons of getting this error.

```
List list = .... ;
for(Object obj:list)
{
Object[] myObj = (Object[])obj;
Long lg = ...;
if(myObj[1]!=null){
lg = ((BigDecimal)myObj[1]).longValue();
}



java.lang.ClassCastException
     at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:...)
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: At `lg = ((BigDecimal)myObj[1]).longValue();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason *is* that `obj` is not an array or that `myObj[1]` is not a BigDecimal.

To debug this, you can add these lines:

```
System.out.println(obj.getClass());
System.out.println(myObj[1].getClass());
```

This will tell you what it actually is.

Answer (score 3):

By that *explicit* cast, you're telling the compiler to trust you that you know what you're doing. Thus, your program *compiles* but crashes because.. `myObj[1]` is **not** a `BigDecimal`, you fooled the compiler and now his best friend (the JVM) is angry.

Comment: Haha, I lolled on the angry compiler. However, the compiles is just fine, it is the JVM that hates him right now :P

Comment: Hahah, now, you get my +1 =P

Comment: Best friend JVM: he is that clever! :)

Answer (score 2):

Because `myObj[1]` is not a `BigDecimal`.
A [ClassCastException](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-solve-javalangclasscastexception-java.html) ocurrs when you try to cast an instance of an Object to a type that it is not.

Answer (score 2):

1. Never work with Raw type Collection: declare your collection with proper Generic types of your case: `List<BigDecimal[]>`
2. `myObj` is not likely a `BigDecimal[]` object, hence a `ClassCastException` can occur.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast an *unSupported* Object type to a `BigDecimal` object. i.e. myObj[1] is not a BigDecimal instance.

`ClassCastException` documenation says that

*Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an 
    object to a subclass of which it is not an instance.*